# 16.04 issues after kernel upgrade

Tags: 16.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.04.2 and also did a kernel upgrade to Kernel 4.8. Since then Ubuntu asks me to enter the passphrase for the encrypted HDD, though it isn't encrypted (passphrase is an empty string). Another issue is that I can shutdown Ubuntu with the command `sudo poweroff -f`. Without sudo or -f Option it doesn't work. How can I fix these issues?

Comment: Last supported kernel on ubuntu 16.04.2 is `4.4.0.72.78`, how and why did you installed `4.8`? try loading old kernels from grub... see if they don't have these problems.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04, the old kernels are not listed in grub

Comment: try old kernels, and what is the output of: `apt-cache policy linux-generic`

Comment: linux-generic:
  Installed: 4.4.0.72.78
  Candidate: 4.4.0.72.78
  Version table:
 *** 4.4.0.72.78 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.4.0.21.22 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Comment: so you are running `4.4.0.72.78` not `4.8`, you can use `uname -r` to find out the running version of kernel too. did you tried older kernels when booting up the system?

Comment: uname -r outputs 4.8.0-46-generic. The old kernels do not appear in grub when booting the system